# eclipse update conflict with polarion subversive connectors

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive, polarion

Before yesterday, I was using the SVNKit Subversive connector, I believe version 1.7.11.  I had some trouble with the SmartBear Collaborator plugin, so I tried to install new connectors, and I set the connector to "Native JavaHL 1.6.15".  This resolved my problem with the Collaborator plugin, but this morning when I checked for Eclipse plugin updates, it prompted me for the following updates:

```
JavaHL 1.6.15 Win32 Binaries (Optional) 4.0.0.I20131101-1700
JavaHL 1.7.9 Win32 Binaries (Optional)  4.0.0.I20131101-1700
JavaHL 1.8.4 Win32 Binaries (Optional)  4.0.0.I20131101-1700
Native JavaHL 1.6 Implementation (Optional) 4.0.0.I20131101-1700
Native JavaHL 1.7 Implementation (Optional) 4.0.0.I20131101-1700
Native JavaHL 1.8 Implementation (Optional) 4.0.0.I20131101-1700
Subversive SVN Connectors   4.0.0.I20131101-1700
SVNKit 1.3.8 Implementation (Optional)  4.0.0.I20131101-1700
SVNKit 1.7.11 Implementation (Optional) 4.0.0.I20131101-1700
SVNKit 1.8.0 Implementation (Optional)  4.0.0.I20131101-1700
```

But it also said:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Native JavaHL 1.8 Implementation (Optional)
4.0.0.I20131101-1700 (org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.javahl18.feature.group 4.0.0.I20131101-1700)
Missing requirement: Native JavaHL 1.8 Implementation (Optional)
4.0.0.I20131101-1700 (org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.javahl18.feature.group 4.0.0.I20131101-1700)
requires 'org.eclipse.team.svn.feature.group [2.0.0.I20131101-1700,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
```

I also noticed that when I look at the "SVN Connector" dropdown in my Subversive preferences, it's currently set to "Native JavaHL 1.6.15", but some of the other choices in the dropdown are interesting ("" is the path to my eclipse distro):

```
Native JavaHL 0x00100000: Cannot load libraries: <pathtoeclipse>\plugins\org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.javahl17.win32_3.0.2.I20130808-1700\ssleay32.dll: The operating system cannot run %1
Native JavaHL 0x00100000: Cannot load libraries: <pathtoeclipse>\plugins\org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.javahl17.win32_3.0.4.I20131116-1700\ssleay32.dll: The operating system cannot run %1
Native JavaHL 1.6.15 r1038135 (SVN 1.6.15)
SVNKit 1.3.8 r9269 (SVN 1.6.18 compatible, all platforms)
SVNKit 1.7.11 r9959_v20130906_1728 (SVN 1.7.11 compatible, all platforms)
SVNKit 1.8.0 r10086_v20131126_1344 (SVN 1.8.1 compatible, all platforms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  I had the wrong set of update sites.  I went back and made sure that I had the prescribed list of update sites for Kepler, and it no longer offered the update to a version 4.0.x plugin.